# Making startup image and icon for web app bookmark on ipad not working

Tags: ipad, web-applications, splash-screen

The goal is to be able to add a bookmark to the ipad's homescreen with an icon and a splash page. Here is the code we used:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content = "yes" /> <!--Makes bookmarked full screen-->

<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="./startup.png" /> <!--Splash page-->

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./apple-touch-icon.png" />  <!--App icon-->
```

The full screen line is working, but the other two are not. Startup.png is the splashpage. Its dimensions are 1024x748 (specified for landscape orientation). apple-touch-icon.png is the icon, and its dimensions are 72x72.

When we add the bookmark to the homescreen, neither the icon nor the splashscreen displays. What is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 1):

In ipad the correct size is 1004x768.

Comment: I wish you people would stipulate, i have found conflicting things all over the web, 1004x768, 768x1004, which way is for gods sake? 1004 WIDTH x 768 HEIGHT or the other way round?